# find a sub-string and match in a big string Reqular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to find a given sub string that exist or match in a big string.

-> a given sub string can contain `\n \r \r`

I try

```
if(preg_match("`".$sub_str."(.*)`im", $str, $matches)){

     //DO something when it true

}
```

for that case I did not know what can be the problems with any given sub string?

Comment: What did you expect it to do? What did it *actually* do?

Comment: find a sub-string and match in big string

Comment: Can you give an example of a string you're trying to match?

Comment: It becomes `false` if there are no matches... I don't understand your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifier `i` is case insensitive flag.

Modifier `m` is multiline flag.

This is, from what I can tell at a very quick glance, a terrible way of doing:

```
$pos = stripos($find_it, $str);
if ($pos !== false) {
    // $find_it exists within $str, $matches contains string after
    $matches = substr($str, $pos);
}
```

The regular expression is simply finding (in a case-insensitive, multiline-aware manner) a (`$find_it`) within another string (`$str`) and placing everything after that into a capturing group (within $matches). The above is a loose match of the code, just faster.

---

Answering your question directly, `preg_match` would return false when `$find_it` did not exist within `$str`.